# Type guard not working properly even though equivalent conditional type works

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, conditional-types, typeguards

Consider the following declaration and uses of a conditional type:

```
type IsIterable<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? Iterable<X> : never
export function isIterableAny(val: any): val is IsIterable<typeof val> {
    return hasValue(val) && typeof (val as any)[Symbol.iterator] === "function"
}
export function isIterableUnknown(val: unknown): val is IsIterable<typeof val> {
    return hasValue(val) && typeof (val as any)[Symbol.iterator] === "function"
}

const num = 1 // 1
const arr = [1, 2, 3] // number[]

type TestNumber = IsIterable<typeof num> // never
type TestArray = IsIterable<typeof arr> // Iterable<number>

if (isIterableAny(num)) { num /* 1 & Iterable<unknown> */ }
if (isIterableUnknown(num)) { num /* never */ }

if (isIterableAny(arr)) { arr /* number[] */ }
if (isIterableUnknown(arr)) { arr /* never */ }
```

**Why do the results of the `isIterable` type guard not correspond to the results of the test types, even though they all use the same conditional type `IsIterable`?**

I notice that the two versions of the type guard work and fail in different/complementary ways, but of course i need a single type guard that works for all inputs

Comment: Why do You need such typeguard?

Comment: @jkaczmarkiewicz: Please what does the reason I need it have to do with anything?

Comment: Because typeguards are designed to recognize type at runtime. Since the type of x is known (not: union, generic, any, unknown, record) there is no need to narrow it.

Apart from that problems can be solved in many different ways so it is better to share more context (eg. What is the end goal?). If it is not a secret ofc.

Comment: @jkaczmarkiewicz This sort of answer is not very useful. It's like asking how to sharpen a knife, and someone says, since you are not currently cutting something, why do you need to sharpen a knife? Irrespective of whether a type-guard is strictly necessary, it should work as per the spec. 

I have an actual need for this type-guard: I need to assert that a value (which could be a union of several types) is an Iterable. I would appreciate any help, if maybe if there is another way to achieve this

Comment: The `typeof val` part is strange, you're trying to compile time infer a type for a runtime type-checked value. Maybe it should rather be `isIterable<T>(...): val is Iterable<T>`

Comment: @JonasWilms That does not work. What would be the type of the value argument in that case? If, as seem logical, it's type is set to T, then there is a type error for the return type of the type guard. Try it and see.

Comment: @JonasWilms And the compile-time type inference works ok, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> type IsIterable<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? Iterable<X> : never;
> ```

By using this, you're discarding all type information related to T other than its iterable attributes. Instead, you just need to exclude from the union `T` all members which don't extend the `Iterable` type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=60&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wZwEkZgoBDAIwBtgAeAFQD4AKANzKqWAC456BKXu07A8+PnFAkUAE3HFSlGrTIoAnozgB+CbxTBWpOHADeAKGMwoa03CjAYSKLhhqwwCAjhsOXOGXFVNX4AbQBlNQBbCggqADpMEnIYaABdOABeLLgAcmR0LBwcgG44AF8LODQyGDQAC1t7R2dEDnxgUoqKsxlgNCoyeyqcfHgUJEjeAEZiswIFcmpgZnHI-jgAMg24VdKAej2dg1IzHr6BobQR+EGoPQmKUhDU2fmkpWXb9a3-KCh9w6rR5QZ6nXr9QaiK4oUZwVDYFD3KhUOAAHzgoygmBQAHNnmi4ABxYD6ZLQWgUTA47EwTTohY1clA0h0uAAJT60BktByZByBJyFByABo4DFYsBVIxXkR3ktmPCcN9toqUACMVZsXj0ujiaTGVAKVSaYwzEA)

```ts
export function isIterable<T>(value: T): value is T extends Iterable<any> ? T : never  {
  try { return typeof (value as any)[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'; }
  catch { return false; }
}

declare const num: 1;
isIterable(num) && num; // never

declare const arr: number[];
isIterable(arr) && arr; // number[]

declare const union: null | string[] | Generator<bigint> | Iterator<number> | Record<'a' | 'b', boolean>;
isIterable(union) && union; // string[] | Generator<bigint>
```

Comment: Ok this is the perfect answer. Interesting that I missed this simple approach. Thanks